# jquerymobile back button is not showing on header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a `mobile site in MVC`, i am new to jquerymobile, i copied the following code from JQM tutorial and paste it in a `View` in MVC

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <p><a href="#about" data-role="button">About this app</a></p>    
  </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="about">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>About This App</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 
    <p>This app rocks! <a href="#home" data-role="button">Go home</a></p>    
  </div>

</div>
```

My problem is, that it shows the `back button on header in the demo` from where i copied the code but when i run this in , `the back button is not there` can any body tell me, why this happened?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting the following attibute on your "page" div:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

e.g.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

Comment: thanks it works , can u pls tell me how can i format this button css?

Comment: You could use a CSS rule like: ui-header ui-btn { ... }. That would give you consistent buttons in the header. But it really depends on the specifics of what you want to do.

Comment: When I put data-add-back-btn="true" in data-role="page" div, it doesn't cause a back button to appear.  I'm using JQM 1.3.1, PhoneGap 2.9, jQuery 1.9.1.  I tested it on  the Android Nexus S emulator and on an HTC One phone.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When using Linux Mint 15, and JQM 1.3.2 with Firefox 23 or Chrome 29, JQM still doesn't add a back button to the header of a non-Ajax loaded page when the page div has data-add-back-btn="true".  But morksinaanab's answer (below) works.

Comment: @devdanke actauly the anwser below is mine, [morksinaanab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578124/morksinaanab) just edited it.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**
OK JQM does have that feature but by default it is disabled, however you can enable it by setting `addBackBtn` to true, or adding the `data-add-back-btn="true"` attribute to the page div.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html - adding back buttons.

In general if you want a back button you just use the `data-rel="back"` attribute, and if you want it displayed in the header then you need to add it there.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header"> 
 <a href="#" data-rel="back">back</a> <h1> Title of page </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
   </div>
<div data-role="footer"><h1>Footer </h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I found what you are referring to, I don't know if JQM always had that feature it was added in one of the recent releases, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: This solution works even when data-add-back-btn="true" doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is for version 1.4.4 and above

```
<div data-role="header" >
        <h1>PAGE_NAME</h1>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all"  data-role="button" role="button">Back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I've found that with 1.4.5 the auto back button is just not rendering regardless of data-add-back-btn="true" placement. and this allows for a manual override.